# Fetch post redirecting to API response body

Tags: javascript, post, backend, fetch-api

I have the following code:

```
 const form = document.querySelector('form');
   form.addEventListener('submit', handleSubmit());

    async function handleSubmit(event) {
        const url = new URL(form.action);
        const formData = new FormData(form);
    
        @type {Parameters<fetch>[1]}
        const fetchOptions = {
            method: form.method,
            body: formData,
        };
    
        const response = await fetch(url, fetchOptions);
        alert (response);
    
        event.preventDefault();
      }
```

With it, I'm trying to upload a file to an external API and receive a server generated id once the upload is complete. However, when the upload completes, I'm redirected to the API response body containing the id. How do I prevent the redirect and instead get the id stored into a variable?

```
fetch(url, fetchOptions)
    .then(function(response)
            {
              return response.json();
            }).then(async function(response)
            {
             alert(response);
            });
```

I tried the above and was still redirected. I also tried moving the `preventDefault` call up to the top of the function as suggested by @Quentin, to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### JavaScript executes your code synchronously until it meets `await`

`event.preventDefault()` is used to cancel the default browser behavior on form submission. It works because a browser uses only 1 thread for JS execution, so the order is the following:

1. Form submit event fired
2. `handleSubmit` function called
3. Default browser action if it is not canceled

Browser expects that `handleSubmit` is a regular function and does not await it. Any async function executes as a regular one until the first await, so in your case order is the following:

1. Form submit event fired
2. `handleSubmit` function is called and executes until the first await
3. Default browser action
4. Browser doing redirect so the rest of `handleSubmit` makes no sense.

I always recommend adding `event.preventDefault()` on top of an event handler if you going to cancel its default behavior. You can try this variant:

```js
async function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const url = new URL(form.action);
    const formData = new FormData(form);

    const fetchOptions = {
        method: form.method,
        body: formData,
    };

    const response = await fetch(url, fetchOptions);
    alert(JSON.stringify(await response.json(), null, 2))
}

form.addEventListener('submit', handleSubmit);
```

```html
<form action="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts" method="POST" id="form">
  <input value="Post Title" name="title"/>
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `preventDefault` **before** the function ends or goes to sleep and returns control to it’s called. i.e. before you hit an `await`.

Since you are calling `preventDefault` too late, the regular form submission continues causing the browser to navigate.

Comment: Didn't seem to work